# In Push Relabel algorithms for max flow why is there not path from source s to sink t?

Tags: algorithm, clrs, network-flow, max-flow, push-relabel

I have difficulty understanding the following lemma from CLRS:

> Let G be a flow network, s and t be source and sink nodes, f be a preflow from s to t, and h be a height function on G.  Then there is no augmenting path from s to t in the residual graph G<sub>f</sub>.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a paraphrased and expanded version of the proof in CLRS, Second Edition.

The intuition behind the proof is that if h is a height function, then we must have that in any path from s to t, the height of the nodes along the path can decrease by at most one in each step (since height functions satisfy the property that h(u) ≤ h(v) + 1, meaning that h(v) ≥ h(u) - 1).  So now suppose that you have an augmenting path in the residual graph that goes from s to t.  In that case, if there's an augmenting path, there must be an augmenting simple path from s to t, so we don't need to worry about cycles.

So let's think about what this simple path must look like.  If there are |V| vertices in the graph, our simple path must have at most |V| vertices in it, which means that it has at most |V| - 1 edges in it.  Because there are at most |V| - 1 edges, and the height of each node can drop by at most one per step, the maximum possible decrease in height from the starting node s is |V| - 1.  Now, we know that h is a height function, which means that h(s) = |V| and h(t) = 0.  But now we have a contradiction - since we start at height |V| and decrease the height by at most |V| - 1, the height at the end of the path has to be at least 1, and since h(t) = 0 we know that this path can't actually end at t.  This contradiction guarantees that our assumption was wrong and that there really is no augmenting path from s to t.

Hope this helps!